# Nav buttons (Questions, Tags, Users...) styling seems screwed up

Tags: support, style

The styling on my navbar buttons is a bit off. The font is a bit strange and the highlighted area overlaps the sort-by tabs. Mucking around in the DOM/Style inspector, if I uncheck the `font-family` property of `.nav a` it is magically fixed.

I've hit Ctrl-F5 (cacheless refresh) to no avail.  Not sure if this is just my browser screwing up or if I'm being AB tested.

[image]

Comment: Apparently this is a problem with an experimental feature in chrome.